# What phrase do you use for when someone finishes something, wins or beats someone not because of their skill or talent but rather their willpower?

Tags: phrases, phrase-choice

Would you tell me what phrase you use for when someone finishes something, wins or beats someone not because of their skill or talent but rather their willpower? Is it natural to say *on sheer willpower*? For example:

> John didn't have the skills to outbox his opponent, but he did it **on sheer willpower**.

Whether that is natural or not, what would you say in the context?

Comment: Your version is correct, and "*... **with/by** sheer willpower*" are more natural. You could also add "***...alone.***" at the end

Comment: The suggestions on how to reword the sentence are fine, but OP's original sentence already looks natural to me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A more common phrasing is **by (sheer) [force of will](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/force%20of%20will)**.

[*By sheer force of will* is actually more common](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=%2A%20force%20of%20will&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=26&smoothing=3&direct_url=t2%3B%2C%2A%20force%20of%20will%3B%2Cc0%3B%2Cs0%3B%3Bsheer%20force%20of%20will%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bby%20force%20of%20will%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Band%20force%20of%20will%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bthe%20force%20of%20will%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Ba%20force%20of%20will%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bmere%20force%20of%20will%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bgreat%20force%20of%20will%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bhis%20force%20of%20will%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bthat%20force%20of%20will%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bindomitable%20force%20of%20will%3B%2Cc0) than just *by force of will*, and [*by* is the most common preposition](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=%2A%20sheer%20force%20of%20will&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=26&smoothing=3&direct_url=t2%3B%2C%2A%20sheer%20force%20of%20will%3B%2Cc0%3B%2Cs0%3B%3Bby%20sheer%20force%20of%20will%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bthrough%20sheer%20force%20of%20will%3B%2Cc0%3B%3BBy%20sheer%20force%20of%20will%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bthe%20sheer%20force%20of%20will%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Band%20sheer%20force%20of%20will%3B%2Cc0%3B%3BThrough%20sheer%20force%20of%20will%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bwith%20sheer%20force%20of%20will%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bfrom%20sheer%20force%20of%20will%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bhis%20sheer%20force%20of%20will%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bthat%20sheer%20force%20of%20will%3B%2Cc0), although *through* is sometimes used too.

Examples:

> [One may accomplish the result by sheer force of will...](https://books.google.com/books?id=FUBVAAAAMAAJ&pg=PA68&dq=%22by%20sheer%20force%20of%20will%22&hl=en&newbks=1&newbks_redir=1&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwj7y7rNkon1AhUFjIkEHe7ABYsQ6AF6BAgDEAI)

> [Lip-synching represents an attempt to slice through this conflict by fiat, to overwhelm the embarrassment by sheer force of will.](https://books.google.com/books?id=-apxDwAAQBAJ&pg=PT39&dq=%22by%20sheer%20force%20of%20will%22&hl=en&newbks=1&newbks_redir=1&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwj-t6T9k4n1AhXHlIkEHcf_BPc4ChDoAXoECAgQAg)

> [In issue # 2 he is vaporized by an atomic bomb blast but manages through sheer force of will to reconstitute himself...](https://books.google.com/books?id=GJAXn53XjnsC&pg=PT130&dq=%22through%20sheer%20force%20of%20will%22&hl=en&newbks=1&newbks_redir=1&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjQjenMlIn1AhUmlIkEHckZCY8Q6AF6BAgGEAI)